# Firewall blocking not the IP-address, but the DNS-name

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

System: CentOS 7
I noticed on my server that some IP-addresses that I blocked are not actually blocked, but continue to hold connections.
I started to look on the iptables-level and saw a strange thing. In some rules, addresses are entered into the rejection not by IP-address, but by DNS-name.
I tried to check this and block one IP-address and as a result, the iptables's rules prescribed blocking the DNS-name of this IP-address
What could be the problem?

I block like this:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule="rule family='ipv4' source address="Х.Х.Х.Х" reject" && firewall-cmd --reload
```

As a result, the following rule appears in iptables:

```
REJECT all -- ec2-Х-Х-Х-Х.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com anywhere reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Comment: Use `-n` parameter for `iptables`.

Comment: Yes, thanx. But this not resolving main problem. This IP is not blocking. Thats is what rule in iptables: REJECT     all  --  X.X.X.X         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable. But this IP address connected and continues to connect.

Comment: And what happens when you change it to a drop instead of reject `firewall-cmd --zone=Putorius --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address=192.168.0.7/32 port port=22 protocol=tcp drop`

Comment: Nothing. But I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem is to use ipset
Install

```
# yum install ipset
```

Create a new ipset and place it in the drop zone

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --new-ipset=netban --type=hash:net --option=maxelem=1000000 --option=family=inet --option=hashsize=4096
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=drop --add-source=ipset:netban
```

Ban IP

```
# firewall-cmd --ipset=netban --add-entry=Х.Х.Х.Х/32
# firewall-cmd --reload
```